# Saving the number of equal notes in variables - Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an API that returns me a JSON with notes ranging from 1 to 5 and I need to store a quantity of equal notes in variables.

Example:

```
var n1 = 5; // Quantity of 10 notes with a value of 1 - [1,1,1,1,1]
var n2 = 3; // Quantity of 3 notes with a value of 2 - [2,2,2]
var n3 = 4; // Quantity of 4 notes with a value of 3 - [3,3,3,3]
```

My JSON looks something like this:

```
[
  {
    "author": "Lorem ipsum",
    "note": "5",
    "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
  }
]
```

And the code I use for this is this:

```
numNotas() {
  this.http.get(this.url).map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
  });
}
```

I tried to use something like `console.log(data.note)` to try to list only the numbers and I could try something to save the same notes in the respective variables, but the `console` returned me `undefined`. So how could I get these same notes and save them in the variables in a correct way?

Comment: Please specify that you are using angular2 and rxjs in your tags.

Comment: @WilomGfx Yes I am. I can print the data normally. My problem is really saving the notes in variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code after the `.map()` operation in your rxjs stream.

You may need to import the `reduce` operator with `import 'ngrx/add/operators/reduce`.

```js
const json = [
  { note: "5" },
  { note: "5" },
  { note: "5" },
  { note: "3" },
  { note: "3" },
]

console.log(
  json
    .map(obj => parseInt(obj.note))
    .reduce((acc, val) => {
      acc[val]++
      return acc
    }, { 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0})
)
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Just another question, how could I retrieve the variables in another function? Well, I'm going to need them to calculate the average grade.

Comment: If you put it between `map()` and `subscribe()` you can access it with `data.1` or `data[1]`. If you need to access the other data as well, leave it out of the rxjs stream and put it inside your `subscribe()` method (or wherever you need it) and assign it to a variable, it will work with vanilla javascript as well as rxjs. (it would also be nice if you accepted my answer if it worked for you :) )